# Get child array from object with filter ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have this object:

```
parent = [{
 child1 : [
  {value:'Jhon', selected:false, status:false},
  {value:'Marie', selected:false, status:false},
  {value:'Less', selected:false, status:false},
 ],
 child2 : [
  {value:'Math', selected:false, status:false},
  {value:'Howard', selected:false, status:false},
  {value:'Jen', selected:false, status:false},
 ]
}]
```

How I get only parameters from child1 in a new array:

```
copyParent = [
  {value:'Jhon', selected:false, status:false},
  {value:'Marie', selected:false, status:false},
  {value:'Less', selected:false, status:false},
]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is off but if you mean this:

```js
parent = [{
 child1: [
  {value:'Jhon', selected:false, status:false},
  {value:'Marie', selected:false, status:false},
  {value:'Less', selected:false, status:false},
 ],
 child2: [
  {value:'Math', selected:false, status:false},
  {value:'Howard', selected:false, status:false},
  {value:'Jen', selected:false, status:false},
 ]
}]
```

the easiest way to copy one part of this is to use the spread operator.

```js
let copyParent = [...parent[0].child1]
```